# Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp getting this error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp
I got error in vue js project when I run project

Answer (score 0):

I get this whenever I'm using Visual Studio (VS) Code and I add something similar to a component

```
@Output() somename = new EventEmitter();
```

- I let VS Code `auto-import` the supporting module. Instead of adding `EventEmitter` to the existing `@angular/core`, VS Code adds a new import to `protractor` which causes the error.

`EventEmitter()` by default imported by `protractor` in VS Code,

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor'; // remove this and import from core

import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

> Note: If you are getting this error and can't remember where the last
> changes were made, try searching for from `protractor` in your code